# Android Application Crashes - where I create object is the reason

Tags: java, android, touch

I am learning to make android applications and so kindly help me.
I am making some application to learn touch inputs.
So I decided to start with getting the touch location.

I made this application

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "in.manas.anurag.firstapp.MESSAGE";
    final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
            String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

When I use the emulator to run this app, it crashes.
However a small change in the application (namely removing "final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);" from the class and putting it as a part of function onTouch makes the app work)

Can someone explain why the first code does not work?

Thank you.

-- The correct code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "in.manas.anurag.firstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
            String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to setContentView before calling findViewById.

Comment: And when is it crashing, before or post the touch event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will work

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "in.manas.anurag.firstapp.MESSAGE";
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
            String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The answer why your code is not running is you are trying to instantiate the view

```
 final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Before  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Before using the `view id` we have to tell from which `layout` it should instantiate the view.

Answer (score 1):

In first code you've put **findViewById** in global variables of class.
But you can call **findViewById** only after **setViewContent** is called.
**onTouchEvent** is called after **setContentView**, so it works.

So this would work:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "in.manas.anurag.firstapp.MESSAGE";
final TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // this is the place for calling findViewById
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, if you want to be able to use your `TextView` everywhere.

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "in.manas.anurag.firstapp.MESSAGE";
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); // after the setContentView
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // set the co-ordinates to the textView.
        textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
        String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for earlier crash was that you were trying to access a view (findViewById) when the class is loaded. The view objects will be available later when you call setContentView() You were setting the view for this activity much later when onCreate() was called, while accessing it at class load time.